# JavaScript getting returned array from function and formatting array items

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, substr

I was having some problem when trying to get the returned array from function in JavaScript. Here is the code:

```
var circle;
var eventNameList = [];
function doBuffer(pos) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/TogetherSG/TogetherServlet?action=GetEvents",
    type: "GET",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, jsondata) {
            showBuffer(p1,p2, eventName, eventDesc, eventVenue);
            getChart();
        });
    },
    error: function (request, state, errors) {
    }
});
}
```

Basically doBuffer() will get all the events from MySQL and pass each event into showBuffer to perform calculation.

```
function showBuffer(p1, p2, eventName, eventDesc, eventVenue) {
// Calculation for distance between two points
var distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1,
        p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
    eventNameList.push(eventName);
}
}
```

For showBuffer, I am calculating each point for the distance. If the distance is less than 1 then I push the point into the array.

Then from the getChart() which I called from the first function above:

```
function getChart(){
    console.log(eventNameList);
}
```

I am printing out the list. However, I am getting the result as:

```
[] events.js:202
[] events.js:202
[] events.js:202
[] events.js:202
[] events.js:202
[] events.js:202
["Event4"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"] events.js:202
["Event4", "Event5", "Event6", "Event7"]
```

I wonder how come it loops so many times. Because from the results returned, I need to format it into a string in this way:

```
'Event4','Event5','Event6','Event7'
```

But I not sure when and where should I formatted it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I wonder how come it loops so many times."* Apparently there are that many elements/properties in `data`.

Comment: But then where should i call the getChart once all the items from servlet has been looped and if it pass the if condition, the point is stored into eventNameList?

Comment: After `$.each(...);` ?

Comment: Oh I see. But do you know how to format the array into the desired string format?

Comment: `var desiredStringFormat = "'" + yourArray.join("','") + "'";`

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Would you mind to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your desired string format of `'Event4','Event5','Event6','Event7'` from an array that contains these single words as elements, you can simply `join` the array elements with `','`, and then just add the missing `'` in the front and back like so:

```
var desiredStringFormat = "'" + yourArray.join("','") + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The getChart function is just console logging the eventNameList as the array is being built. If you move the getChart function out of the loop it will only log the array after it is finished the loop. You can put it after the loop, after the AJAX, or anywhere besides where it is now and it will display fine. You are watching your code in action and your eyes are playing tricks on you.